# Routing to another function if first function fails in R

Tags: r, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I'm calling a function in R

```
for(i in 1:nrow(ListA)){Produce_Output(ListA$ColumnA[i], ListA$ColumnB[i])}
```

This function produces either an ETS or Auto.Arima model based on the best fit. However some data does not allow for forecasting using this model and brings back errors (understandable). What I would like is the ability to pass the variables ColumnA and ColumnB to another function if the function "Produce_Output" fails.

I can use "Try" to just ignore the errors but that's not what I am after. Looking at the TryCatch function this appears(maybe) to the area I need to look at however I can only see references to how to return a handles rather than pass to activate another function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax (updated to a reproduceable example:)

```
ListA <- data.frame(ColumnA = c(1,2,3,4),
                    ColumnB = c("a","b","c","d"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Produce_Output <- function(i,j){
  if(i %in% c(2,4)){
    stop("Error in Produce Output")
  }
  cat(" \n# Produce Output: ", i, j)
}

another_function <- function(i,j){
  cat("\n#another function:", i, j)
}

for(i in 1:nrow(ListA)){
  tryCatch(
    Produce_Output(ListA$ColumnA[i], ListA$ColumnB[i]),
    error = function(ex){
      warning("Had an error - ", ex)
      another_function(ListA$ColumnA[i], ListA$ColumnB[i])
    })

}
```

Which produces this output:

```
# Produce Output:  1 a
# another_function: 2 b 
# Produce Output:  3 c
# another_function: 4 dWarning messages:
1: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Had an error - Error in Produce_Output(ListA$ColumnA[i], ListA$ColumnB[i]): Error in Produce Output

2: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Had an error - Error in Produce_Output(ListA$ColumnA[i], ListA$ColumnB[i]): Error in Produce Output
```

Avoiding the for loop by using `apply()` example:

```
f <- function(x){
  tryCatch(
    Produce_Output(x[["ColumnA"]], x[["ColumnB"]]),
    error = function(ex){
      warning("Had an error - ", ex)
      another_function(x[["ColumnA"]], x[["ColumnB"]])
    })
}

out <- apply(ListA, 1, f)

# Produce Output:  1 a
# another_function: 2 b 
# Produce Output:  3 c
# another_function: 4 dWarning messages:
1: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Had an error - Error in Produce_Output(ListA$ColumnA[i], ListA$ColumnB[i]): Error in Produce Output

2: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Had an error - Error in Produce_Output(ListA$ColumnA[i], ListA$ColumnB[i]): Error in Produce Output
```

Comment: The first part works if I strip out the  another_function(ListA$ColumnA[i], ListA$ColumnB[i]), if I don't it just seems to hang which might indicate a loop but i'm not sure how its looping

Comment: I updated with a reproducible example, perhaps it is something within the functions you are using that is causing it to hang?